# How to know Optaplanner solving has ended?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I have initialized and started a solver, I have registered a listener for the best solution change but I would also like to know when solving has ended.
I have configured the logger and it correctly shows when the solver has stopped solving (when the termination condition is met or when it is terminated early). I would like to know when  the solver has finished, whichever way it ended.

Here's my current code for listening for best solution changes

```
solver.addEventListener(new SolverEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void bestSolutionChanged(BestSolutionChangedEvent bestSolutionChangedEvent) {
        //Get the new best solution
    }
});
```

I have gone through the documentation several times but couldn't find what I need. Any ideas? Thanks.
**PS:** I'm using Optaplanner 6.0.1 final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `Solver.solve()` method returns.

Note when the `daemon` mode is explicitly set to `true`, that will only happen if `Solver.terminateEarly()` is called from another thread. Otherwise it will happen after the `Termination` says it's done too.

Comment: Thanks @Geoffrey your answers have all been very useful in learning optaplanner